# Are there any languages which allow operator precedence to be overloaded?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

Consider this C++ code:

```
struct A {
    A operator*(A a) { return A(); }  // A*A -> A
};
struct B {
    A operator*(B b) { return A(); }  // B*B -> A
};

int main() {
    A t2 = B()*B() * A(); // works
    A t1 = A() * B()*B(); // errors
    return 0;
}
```

`A*B` is not allowed, but `B*B` is. Do languages exist which will choose their operator precedence rules based on the types of the variables?

Comment: I sure hope not -- I pity the people debugging the parser.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#op:_Operators

Comment: @larsmans: I thought that quotation originated at an anonymous c++ compiler writers meeting.

Comment: @phimuemue But do the types change the precedence in ALGOL? Otherwise, it's just like Prolog where you can set the precedence but not change it later.

Comment: Programmers exist who can use parenthesis to determine the orders of operations.

Comment: @Vector: [If mathematicians are allowed to do it...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Geometric_interpretation) - _"Here, the parentheses may be omitted without causing ambiguity, since the dot product cannot be evaluated first"_

Comment: @Eric - Granted. But if your compiler suffers from ambiguity, why not help it along? I am not positive, but I believe you could set up your order of operations correctly to cover any sort of operation by rearranging the order of variables and using appropriate parenthesis, so I wonder why all the fuss. I suppose you are looking for a generic solution that would not require the programmer to mess with things dependending on the data types and operations, but have the compiler handle it all automatically. So, OK - +1 for this interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my original question can in fact be expressed in C++:

```
struct A {
    friend A operator*(A const& a1, A const &a2) { return A(); }  // A*A -> A
};
struct B {
    friend A operator*(B const& a, B const &b) { return A(); }  // B*B -> A
};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct unresolved_multiply {
    A const& a;
    B const& b;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
unresolved_multiply<A, B> operator*(A const& a, B const &b) {
    return {a, b};
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
auto operator*(unresolved_multiply<A, B> const& ab, C const &c) {
    return ab.a * (ab.b * c);
}

int main() {
    A t1 = B()*B() * A();   // works
    A t2 = A() * B()*B();   // works
    A t3 = (A() * B())*B(); // works...
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, disregarding parentheses like this is a terrible idea.